# multiple update on codeigniter with update batch

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$ID = $this->input->post('barang');
$reslt = array();
foreach($ID AS $key => $val){
    $reslt[] = array(
    "id" => $ID[$key],
    "stok"  => $_POST['qty'][$key]);
}

$this->db->update_batch('barang', $reslt, 'id');
```

#### Error

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: id
>
> Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php
>
> Line Number: 1955
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: E:\xampp\htdocs\restly\application\controllers\admin.php Line:
> 343 Function: update_batch
>
> File: E:\xampp\htdocs\restly\index.php Line: 315 Function:
> require_once

Can any body help me?

Comment: You have typo error here `$_POST['qty'][$key]);` Change this to `$_POST['qty'][$key])`

Answer (score 0):

You have added semicolon extra,just remove that.
Updated code:

```
$reslt[] = array(
                    "id" => $ID[$key],
                    "stok"  => $_POST['qty'][$key])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$ID = $this->input->post('barang');
    $reslt = array();
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($ID); $x++){
        {
            $reslt[] = array(
                        "id" => $ID[$x],
                        "stok"  => $_POST['qty'][$x]
                        );
        }
    $this->db->update_batch('barang', $reslt, 'id');
```

Update this code into your code ..and check it and accept if it works!

Comment: hi bro @Madhur, I was try this into my code, but still have an error, could you help me? see in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654976/codeigniter-batch-update-for-checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You have typo error here

`$_POST['qty'][$key]);`

Change this to

`$_POST['qty'][$key])`

Your Final `foreach` should be:

```
foreach($ID AS $key => $val){
$reslt[] = array(
    "id"    => $ID[$key],
    "stok"  => $_POST['qty'][$key])
}
```