# Codeigniter batch update for checkbox

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, batch-updates, codeigniter-query-builder

I have a situation like this, I want to update some data where the input are checkboxes, I was tried this code below. Data already saved in database, but data saved in another row,

> For example :  I checked color red, yellow and grey for BirdA and I checked dark and blue for BirdD at the same time.
> In database, color for BirdA saved correctly, but for the 2nd bird, dark and blue saved on BirdB (*Should be save on BirdD*)

I want to solve my problem above, so data should be save in the right place in database. Please check my code below :

**My Db Table:**

```
=============================================
| birds | red | blue | grey | yellow | dark | 
=============================================
| BirdA |  0  |   0  |   0  |   0    |   0  |
| BirdB |  0  |   0  |   0  |   0    |   0  |
| BirdC |  0  |   0  |   0  |   0    |   0  |
| BirdD |  0  |   0  |   0  |   0    |   0  |
=============================================
```

**View :**

```
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="birds[]" value='<?php echo $dp['birds']; ?>' /><?php echo $dp['birds']; ?></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="text" name="qtt[]" value='<?php echo $dp['qtt']; ?>' tabindex="2" style="width:30px;" /></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="red[]" value='1' <?php if($dp['red']==1) { echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="blue[]" value='1' <?php if($dp['blue']==1) { echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="grey[]" value='1' <?php if($dp['grey']==1) { echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="yellow[]" value='1' <?php if($dp['yellow']==1) { echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="dark[]" value='1' <?php if($dp['dark']==1) { echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /></td>
  </tr>
```

**And the controller :**

```
    $birds= $this->input->post("birds");
        if (empty($this->input->post("birds"))){
            $birds= 0;
        }
    $qtt= $this->input->post("qtt");
        if (empty($this->input->post("qtt"))){
            $qtt= 0;
        }
    $red= $this->input->post("red");
        if (empty($this->input->post("red"))){
            $red= 0;
        }
    $blue= $this->input->post("blue");
        if (empty($this->input->post("blue"))){
            $blue= 0;
        }
    $grey= $this->input->post("grey");
        if (empty($this->input->post("grey"))){
            $grey= 0;
        }
    $yellow= $this->input->post("yellow");
        if (empty($this->input->post("yellow"))){
            $yellow= 0;
        }
    $dark= $this->input->post("dark");
        if (empty($this->input->post("dark"))){
            $dark= 0;
        }

    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($birds); $x++){
        $reslt[$x] = array(
            "birds"    => $birds[$x],
            "qtt"  => $qtt[$x],
            "red"  => $red[$x],
            "blue"  => $blue[$x],
            "grey"  => $grey[$x],
            "yellow"  => $yellow[$x],
            "dark"  => $dark[$x]
            );
        }
        $this->db->update_batch('db_birds', $reslt, 'birds');
```

**after I execute that code, php has an error like this :**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: x

Filename: controllers/....

Line Number: 613

Backtrace:

File: /home/.....
Line: 613
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/..../index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 3

Filename: controllers/....

Line Number: 621

Backtrace:

File: /home/....
Line: 621
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/..../index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 3

Filename: controllers/...

Line Number: 622

Backtrace:

File: /home/...
Line: 622
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/.../index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 4

Filename: controllers/...

Line Number: 620

Backtrace:

File: /home/...
Line: 620
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/.../index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 4

Filename: controllers/...

Line Number: 621

Backtrace:

File: /home/...
Line: 621
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/.../index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 4

Filename: controllers/...

Line Number: 622

Backtrace:

File: /home/...
Line: 622
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/.../index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 5

Filename: controllers/...

Line Number: 618

Backtrace:

File: /home/...
Line: 618
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/.../index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

......
```

Thank you, Best Regards

Comment: so what actually you want??

Comment: I want to save those batch data (in checkbox) in the right place in database

Comment: change this  `$reslt[$x] ` to  `$reslt[]`

Comment: I have tried this, nothing happen, no data saved

Comment: what you get in `sizeof($birds);`??

Comment: have you tried my code?

Comment: $birds is a word, like my example BirdA, BirdB, etc (no spacing in value), not integer/number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224013/discussion-between-kumar-and-karisma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller Code:-**

```
for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($birds); $x++){
        $reslt[$x] = array(
            "birds"    => $birds[$x],
            "qtt"  => $qtt[$x],
            "red"  => $red[$x],
            "blue"  => $blue[$x],
            "grey"  => $grey[$x],
            "yellow"  => $yellow[$x],
            "dark"  => $dark[$x]
            );
        }
$this->db->update_batch('db_birds', $reslt, 'birds');
```

**Change is in your view code:-**

```
 <?php


//sql Query.
//execute Query.


$ii=0;
foreach($dps as $dp){
      $iii = $ii++; 
 <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="birds[<?php echo $iii;?>]" value='<?php echo $dp['birds']; ?>' /><?php echo $dp['birds']; ?></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="text" name="qtt[]" value='<?php echo $dp['qtt']; ?>' tabindex="2" style="width:30px;" /></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="red[<?php echo $iii;?>]" value='1' <?php if($dp['red']==1) { echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="blue[<?php echo $iii;?>]" value='1' <?php if($dp['blue']==1) { echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="grey[<?php echo $iii;?>]" value='1' <?php if($dp['grey']==1) { echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="yellow[<?php echo $iii;?>]" value='1' <?php if($dp['yellow']==1) { echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /></td>
    <td><p align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="dark[<?php echo $iii;?>]" value='1' <?php if($dp['dark']==1) { echo " checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /></td>
  </tr>
  }
  
  
?>
```

Comment: error `show Message: Undefined offset: 3` `Message: Undefined variable: x` ...
see on this capture 
http://prntscr.com/vc8j8n
http://prntscr.com/vc8jfq

Comment: do u have another solution bro @KUMAR ?

Comment: @karisma now see & check my updated answer please & let me know what happens??

Comment: It's work bro, but with few modification, thanks bro!

Comment: @karisma great to hear from you that its work for you, enjoy & happy Coding...

Comment: @karisma  who helps you in some modifications.

Comment: I modify myself